# Find by two separate data types with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to be able to find a user in my MongoDB (using Mongoose) by either a username or ID.

Using: `User.find({ $or: [ { _id: req.params.userId }, { username: req.params.userId } ]}, ...` throws an error when I pass it a string:

> Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"username\" at path \"_id\" for model \"User\""

I understand why I'm getting the error, but is there an easy way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test whether `req.params.userId` is a valid `ObjectId` and then assemble your query based on that:

```
let query = {};
if (req.params.userId.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
    query._id = req.params.userId;
}
else {
    query.username = req.params.userId;
}
User.find(query, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid` but was hoping there was a cleaner, single line way! I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @Damien Thanks. I don't recommend using that `isValid` method because it has the quirky behavior of considering _any_ 12 character string as valid.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks.